# I'm using Visual studio 2019 and my project's name ends with .Sln insted of .cpp

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming I use visual studio 2019 and when I'm creating a new project the project's name always end with .Sln instead of .cpp

Comment: Yup, it is the way Visual Studion works, you'll not find any CPP files if you have created an empty project, and if you have used predefined templates to create a project then VS will create some .H and .CPP files for you.

Comment: A solution (sln) consists of 1..n project files (vcxproj) and a project file has 1..n source (cpp) and header (h / hpp) files. The project file is a container with all kinds of compiler settings for all contained source files. You can also compile individual source files through cl.exe on the command line but that's quite unhandy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.sln` is a diminutive for solution, it's a Visual Studio executable that has some basic configurations like the VS version you are using, the project id, name, and things like that, as you execute this, it will open your `.vcxproj` that has all the global configurations of the project, `.cpp` file names, etc. and will open your project. If you look in your project folder you should have at least a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 3):

.sln is the file visual studio uses to organize the project. I believe you will find one or multiple .cpp files in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

SLN is the solution file. It is used to compile the solution and other informations. You can add classes (.cpp/.h) in your project where you can write C++ code.